# oracledb_exporter binary files

Tags: oracle, prometheus

There is Prometheus Oracle database exporter https://github.com/iamseth/oracledb_exporter

Under Running section, "/path/to/binary -l log.level error -l web.listen-address 9161" is not clear me.
Here I am not getting what is "/path/to/binary" mean, is it oracle client or /usr/bin/ path, or which file I need to replace with? I have RHEL7.3

After setting DATA_SOURCE_NAME is set correctly and running below commman, its throwing error (no such cmd - /path/to/binary)
/path/to/binary -l log.level error -l web.listen-address 9161

Please refer ZIP/clone from location :-https://github.com/iamseth/oracledb_exporter

Oracle database exporter should start and fetch required values/status from oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're still looking for the answer:

- The easiest way is to download the pre-compiled version. Otherwise you will need to compile it yourself: https://github.com/iamseth/oracledb_exporter/releases
- Download the version you want e.g. '*oracledb_exporter.0.2.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz*' and unzip it.
- You will get a folder '*oracledb_exporter.0.2.2.linux-amd64*' which conatins two files:

  1. default-metrics.toml
  2. oracledb_exporter
- The second one is the one you need to execute:
  -> /path_to/oracledb_exporter.0.2.2.linux-amd64/oracledb_exporter log.level error web.listen-address 9161